# Datatables.js Hiding Column Shrinks Table

Tags: css, datatables

I am attempting to add a hidden column to my datatable. I set it up in the Columns definitions to add a CSS class to the last column. That CSS class simply sets the display to none thus hiding the column. It appears to be working however it's shrinking my table for some reason. Why is it doing this?

[image]

```
var table = $('#myTable').dataTable({
"columns": [
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      { className: "hide_column" },
    ]
});

.hide_column{
     display: none;
}


<table id="myTable" class="row-border">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="bg-green">
                                    <th style="white-space: nowrap;">ID</th>
                                    <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Sub ID</th>
                                    <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Service Group</th>
                                    <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Field ID</th>
                                    <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Message</th>
                                    <th style="white-space: nowrap; width: 40%;">Instructions</th>
                                    <th>Field ID</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="myTableBody"></tbody>
                        </table>
```